# DNS configuration problem with BIND9

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, dns, bind

Following is my BIND9 configuration.
The domain I want to configure is `home.lan`. It is the home network.

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local` is:

```
zone "home.lan" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db";
};
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.options` is:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Since it is a personal network, I do not need any forwarders section,so did not configure it.

`/etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db`

```
; Use semicolons to add comments.
; Host-to-IP Address DNS Pointers for home.lan
; Note: The extra “.” at the end of the domain names are important.

; The following parameters set when DNS records will expire, etc.
; Importantly, the serial number must always be iterated upward to prevent
; undesirable consequences. A good format to use is YYYYMMDDII where
; the II index is in case you make more that one change in the same day.
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
home.lan. IN SOA ubuntu.home.lan. hostmaster.home.lan. kalu.home.lan. (
    2008080901 ; serial
    8H ; refresh
    4H ; retry
    4W ; expire
    1D ; minimum
)

; NS indicates that ubuntu is the name server on home.lan
; MX indicates that ubuntu is (also) the mail server on home.lan
home.lan. IN NS kalu.home.lan.
home.lan. IN MX 10 ubuntu.home.lan.

$ORIGIN home.lan.

; Set the address for localhost.home.lan
localhost    IN A 127.0.0.1

; Set the hostnames in alphabetical order
home         IN A 192.168.1.7
ntinstall    IN A 192.168.1.7
kalu         IN A 192.168.1.7
router       IN A 192.168.1.1
server       IN A 192.168.1.5
```

and `/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`:

```
; IP Address-to-Host DNS Pointers for the 192.168.1 subnet
@ IN SOA ubuntu.home.lan. hostmaster.home.lan. (
    2008080901 ; serial
    8H ; refresh
    4H ; retry
    4W ; expire
    1D ; minimum
)
; define the authoritative name server
           IN NS ubuntu.home.lan.
; our hosts, in numeric order
1         IN PTR router.home.lan.
2         IN PTR ubuntu.home.lan.
3         IN PTR ntinstall.home.lan.
4         IN PTR kalu.home.lan.
```

`/etc/hostnames`:

```
kalu
```

The `/etc/resolv.conf` on the BIND9 server is:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search home.lan


at the client machine
/etc/resolv.conf

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.7
search home.lan
```

From client machine when I try to ping I get the following results:

```
$ ping kalu.home.lan
ping: unknown host kalu.home.lan
```

There is no file like `/var/log/bind.log`
So I amnot sure where to look for it.

Here is `dig` output at server:

dig kalu.home.lan

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> kalu.home.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 36937
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kalu.home.lan.         IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 11 23:59:03 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31
```

At the client machine `dig kalu.home.lan` gives the following results:

```
 dig kalu.home.lan

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> kalu.home.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 25537
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kalu.home.lan.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           7388    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2013101101 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 11 23:59:34 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106
```

What is the mistake in above DNS configuration?
`kalu` is the hostname of machine on which I am configuring all this.

To enable logging in BIND9 `rndc querylog` it shows:

```
Oct 12 01:42:16 ubuntu named[11408]: dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db:11: near 'kalu.home.lan.': not a valid number
Oct 12 01:42:16 ubuntu named[11408]: zone home.lan/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db failed: not a valid number
Oct 12 01:42:16 ubuntu named[11408]: zone home.lan/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Oct 12 01:42:16 ubuntu named[11408]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Oct 12 01:42:16 ubuntu named[11408]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 5
```

and I see:

```
 sudo named-checkzone home.lan home.lan.db
[sudo] password for hp: 
zone home.lan/IN: loading from master file home.lan.db failed: file not found
zone home.lan/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Comment: what does `dig kalu.home.lan` respond? did you check the logfiles to ensure bind loaded the zone files correctly?

Comment: I updated the answer but surprisingly there is no file /var/log/bind.log

Answer (score 2):

The IPs for  files "`home.lan.db`" and "`rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`" don't match. Just correct them.

```
/etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db

; Set the hostnames in alphabetical order
home         IN A 192.168.1.7
ntinstall    IN A 192.168.1.7
kalu         IN A 192.168.1.7
router       IN A 192.168.1.1
server       IN A 192.168.1.5


/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa

; our hosts, in numeric order
1         IN PTR router.home.lan.
2         IN PTR ubuntu.home.lan.
3         IN PTR ntinstall.home.lan.
4         IN PTR kalu.home.lan.

############

# For example, the correct one should be:
/etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db

; Set the hostnames in alphabetical order
kalu         IN A 192.168.1.4
ntinstall    IN A 192.168.1.3
router       IN A 192.168.1.1
ubuntu       IN A 192.168.1.2


/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa

; our hosts, in numeric order
1         IN PTR router.home.lan.
2         IN PTR ubuntu.home.lan.
3         IN PTR ntinstall.home.lan.
4         IN PTR kalu.home.lan.
```